# Converting MongoDB query to jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

How would you write a query like this

`db.collection.find({$expr: {$lte: [{ $mod: [ '$created_at', 3600 ] }, 59]}});`

using the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb extension

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to write that query using the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb extension, so I fetched the records and implemented the logic to filter them myself in the code.

Answer (score 1):

use the raw expression  [following the documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#raw-expressions)

```
YourModel::whereRaw([
            '$expr' => [
                '$lte' => [
                    [
                        '$mod' => [
                            '$created_at', 3600
                        ],
                        59
                    ]
                 ]
            ]
        ])->get();
```